# MapView is not shown correctly

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am using `MapView` inside a `RecycleView` in android.

here is my `xml` code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and:

```
private fun initializeMap() {

            val mapView : MapView = binding.root.findViewById(R.id.map_view)
            mapView?.let {
                mapView.onCreate(null)
                mapView.getMapAsync(this)
            }
        }

override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(fragment.context)
            googleMap = map
            googleMap?.let {

                it.setOnMapLoadedCallback { this }
                it.setOnMapClickListener { this }
                it.uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)
                it.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = false
            }
        }

        override fun onMapLoaded() {

        }


        override fun onMapClick(p0: LatLng?) {

        }
```

the map that appear is like following

[image]

and it takes a lot of time tp appear and also does not appear direct, I scroll a lot

also the methods `onMapLoaded()` and `onMapClick()` does not call

Comment: Why do you want to use a map inside recyclerview ? Its a bad idea

Comment: it is a business requirement, there is a large screen with so many items so we are using recycle view with fast adapter to implement it , one of the items is map, I tried it using map fragment and it was working, but the recycle was used inside fragment, and nested fragments are not recommended also

Comment: If you just want to show stationary image of a place then you can get static image of certain area using LatLng . See https://staticmapmaker.com/google/

Comment: That is looks like a good idea , I will try it and get back to you, Thanks

Comment: You can get with help of latitude and logitude too . see https://www.codexworld.com/google-maps-image-using-google-static-maps-api/

Comment: @ManoharReddy it is very good solution, but what I need is to draw a circle around the latitude and longitude of the user, can you help in this

Comment: Why not just add another imageview with circle on top of map

Comment: @ManoharReddy I did that already but I thought it is workaround

Answer (score 0):

As you set `it.uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)` and `it.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = false` use `MapView` in [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite):

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                map:cameraZoom="<ZOOM>"
                map:mapType="normal"
                map:liteMode="true">
```

[Here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LiteListDemoActivity.java) you can find Official example of using `MapView` inside `RecyclerView` and [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/res/layout/lite_list_demo_row.xml) `MapView` layout settings:

> ```
> <!-- MapView in lite mode. Note that it needs to be initialised
>      programmatically before it can be used. -->
> <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
>     android:id="@+id/lite_listrow_map"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="150dp"
>     map:liteMode="true" map:mapType="none" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

this my map.xml file

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

And this is java class

```
public class map extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
GoogleMap mMap;
private MapView mapView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map,null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
 LatLng ahmedabad = new LatLng(23.022505, 72.571365);
        BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icons8fiat50060);

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(ahmedabad)
            .title("Current Location")
            .snippet("Thinking of finding some thing...")
            .icon(icon);

     googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ahmedabad,30f));
  }
```

}
this is  quite easy i think this will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I call mapView.onResume() after mapView.onCreate(null) resolves the issue.

Comment: You could add more detail about it